# importJSON concatenate and display results in single cell separated by commas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, foursquare

I'm currently using importJSON to import foursquare venue photo data into google sheets. This works well but the results ends up splitting over multiple cells with a row for each photo and a column for prefix,suffix, width and height.

The code in the first prefix cell looks like this:

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4bc20cf2920eb7134b881b2c?oauth_token=TOMSBZZ3OPENPMWHFITMVLEM4YQA41UCTSPRPWUCBQIDXQ3C&v=20140304", "/response/venue/photos/groups/items/prefix,/response/venue/photos/groups/items/width,/response/venue/photos/groups/items/height,/response/venue/photos/groups/items/suffix", "noHeaders")
```

and gathers all the information for the other cells (except for the URL column) too.

[image]

I have a URL column and the code in each creates a link from the prefix, suffix, width and height like so (Q = prefix, S = suffix, T = Width, R = height):

```
= CONCATENATE(Q2,S2,"x",T2,R2)
```

This generates a link for each photo for the venue.

What I'd like to be able to do is generate the URL for all photos and store them all in the same cell separated by commas.

```
URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4
```

Unfortunately I can't post photos, which would explain it a lot easier.

Thanks for any help,

Rory

Answer (score 0):

try this formula:

```
join(",",unique(arrayformula(Q2:Q&S2:S&"x"&T2:T&R2:R)))
```

you may have an extra "x" in your list...

Comment: I don't know the importJSON formula you used, is it a google apps script? if it is, you  could also modified your script so it give you the result no?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, i should have mentioned that it is a script that I found here http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json . I'll have a look into using the above now. I thought about editing it but there is hopefully an easier way as my google apps skills aren't great.